# UWP EasClientDeviceInformation.SystemFirmwareVersion always returns 0

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, firmware

I'm trying to get information about desktop or mobile device in UWP (Universal Windows Platform) using EasClientDeviceInformation class for that. When reading [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.systemfirmwareversion#Windows_Security_ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning_EasClientDeviceInformation_SystemFirmwareVersion) about SystemFirmwareVersion or SystemHardwarVersion it notes that "The SystemFirmwareVersion property is retrieved from the registry. If the registry can't be read for any reason, SystemFirmwareVersion is returned as an empty string."
Which in my case ALWAYS returns an empty string. While reading more about UWP I found that UWP apps run in sandbox mode and therefore lacking access to registry in the first place.

So how is this method ever able to get its information from device?

Is there way to let UWP read registry keys and feed results into desired methods to make them work ?

If it is possible to get access to registry (for reading only) is it possible to retrieve even more information about the device (like CPU model, amount of RAM, GPU model etc.) because I know that by default UWP cannot get access to this information?

Note: this app will used for personal use on limited devices so it doesn't need validation from microsoft, mainly on Surface pro's and Windows phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the properties in `EasClientDeviceInformation` depend on the device manufacturer setting them correctly, or on the device being of a specific kind (in particular, the `SystemFirmwareVersion` is probably only ever present on Windows Phone, not Windows Desktop, and might even be missing there in some cases).

It is not true that *"UWP apps [lack] access to registry"* nor is it true that *"UWP cannot get access to [CPU, GPU, etc.]."*

By policy, the Registry APIs are not supported for UWP apps because they present a supportability problem (Registry keys are mostly implementation details of the OS, not meant for apps to rely on) but you definitely have access if you call the Registry APIs directly. Additionally, some Registry keys are protected by security ACLs so you can't read and / or write them.

You can use APIs like `Windows.Devices.Enumeration`, `DirectX`, or various Win32 APIs to get information about the system.